# Should I use Timer or Concurrency Service to change my ObservableObject of Date?

Tags: java

I have an `ObservableValue` object of `LocalDate`:

```
private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> cal = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "cal", LocalDate.now());
```

I want to change the value of `cal` object periodically to `LocalDate.now`. What is preferable for this: `Timer` or `Concurrency` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ScheduledThreadExecutor`

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // Change your date object
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) of Timer

> Java 5.0 introduced the `java.util.concurrent` package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`
>   which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate
>   or delay. It is effectively a **more versatile replacement for the**
>   **`Timer`/`TimerTask` combination**, as it allows **multiple service threads**,
>   **accepts various time units**, and **doesn't require subclassing `TimerTask`**
>   (just implement `Runnable`).

Comment: Can you explain why is it preferable over `Timer`?